# How often can a new Twitter archive be requested?

Tags: twitter, twitter-archive

The *Twitter archive* feature works by requesting an archive; once an archive is ready, receiving an email with a link to twitter, visiting twitter, and downloading the archive as a zip file.

Subsequently, in the user interface within twitter.com, the option to request the archive is changed to `Resend email`, and no new archive can be requested.

Would it ever change back to make it possible to request an archive again, to get all the updated tweets?  When / how?

Comment: Yes it does change back, not sure when it did, but it comes at least a few months since first request

Answer (score 1):

It would appear that a new archive of your tweets from Twitter can be requested every **seven days** or so.

Source: personal experience of now seeing a button to request an archive again, roughly 7 days after the date of the prior archive that has been generated.

Answer (score 1):

In my case, it took about 3 weeks for my request archive to become undimmed. I never got it to change  to the resend email link. Using safari  on a macbook pro running os10.9.1 with all updates applied. I also never got an email with the link in it containing the archive dl thing.

My source for this is also personal experience. 
Here is a screenshot of the current window from google chrome.
https://www.dropbox.com/s/zzf4em8azouynfi/Screen%20Shot%202014-01-15%20at%2012.42.57%20PM.png

Hope that helps.